# Query mysql para agrupar los estados de una llamada en un estado concreto

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta para sacar los estados de una llamada que ya tiene un estado concreto.

Es decir, en mi aplicación, necesito sacar un historico de las llamadas que se han pasado a comerciales, el estado en el que se encuentran dichas llamadas.

Esta es la query que estoy tratando de hacer, pero solo me devuelve un registro:

```
SELECT * FROM `cita` 
inner join llamada as llma on cita.id_llamada = llma.id 
INNER join llamada_estado on llma.id_estado = llamada_estado.id 
INNER join cita_estado on cita.id_estado = cita_estado.id
inner join llamada on llamada.id_teleoperadora = users.id
where llamada_estado.id = 5
group by llamada_estado.desc
```

Las relaciones son las siguientes, las llamadas se relacionan con las citas, es decir una llamada cuando se ha pasado a comerciales tiene el estado 5 y pasa a ser una cita, las citas también tienen un estado que se relacionan con cita_estado y lo primero de todo es que las llamadas las gestiona una teleoperadora que tiene un id y se relaciona en la tabla user con su id

No puedo poner datos por ley de protección de datos... Se que no está bien plantear la pregunta así, pero no puedo poner datos.

pero pongo la estructura de las tablas al menos:

```
CREATE TABLE `cita` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nomape` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cp` char(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `movil` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_comercial` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_comercial2` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_llamada` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_estado` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**tabla llamada**

```
CREATE TABLE `llamada` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nomape` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cp` char(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `movil` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_teleoperadora` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_listado` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_estado` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fecha_asignacion` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**tabla llamada_estado**

```
CREATE TABLE `llamada_estado` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clase_span` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clase` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hex` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `llamada_estado`
--

INSERT INTO `llamada_estado` (`id`, `nombre`, `desc`, `clase_span`, `clase`, `hex`) VALUES
(1, 'nueva', 'NUEVA', 'badge bg-primary text-white', 'primary', '#5c80d1'),
(2, 'pendiente', 'PENDIENTE', 'badge bg-warning text-white', 'warning', '#f3b760'),
(3, 'anulada', 'ANULADA', 'badge bg-danger text-white', 'danger', '#d26a5c'),
(4, 'confirmada', 'CONFIRMADA', 'badge bg-success text-white', 'success', '#46c37b'),
(5, 'comercializada', 'PASADA A COMERCIALES', 'badge bg-info text-white', 'info', '#70b9eb'),
(6, 'confirmada-ausente', 'CONFIRMADA/AUSENTE', 'badge bg-secondary text-white', 'secondary', '#6c757d'),
(7, 'confirmada-anulada', 'CONFIRMADA/ANULADA', 'badge bg-dark text-white', 'dark', '#343a40');
```

**tabla cita estado**

```
CREATE TABLE `cita_estado` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clase_span` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clase` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `cita_estado`
--

INSERT INTO `cita_estado` (`id`, `nombre`, `desc`, `clase_span`, `clase`) VALUES
(1, 'nueva', 'NUEVA', 'badge bg-info text-white', 'info'),
(2, 'confirmada', 'CONFIRMADA', 'badge bg-success text-white', 'success'),
(3, 'pendiente', 'PENDIENTE', 'badge bg-warning text-white', 'warning'),
(4, 'nula', 'NULA', 'badge bg-danger text-white', 'danger'),
(5, 'aplazada', 'APLAZADA', 'badge bg-secondary text-white', 'secondary'),
(6, 'ausente', 'AUSENTE', 'badge bg-primary text-white', 'primary'),
(7, 'venta', 'VENTA', 'badge bg-gold text-white', 'gold');
```

**tabla usuarios**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_empleado` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dni` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sede` char(6) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'GR',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

lo que necesito es hacer una consulta que por id de teleoperadora, aparezcan las llamadas con estado pasadas a comerciales y estas a su vez, el estado de la cita. y que sea usa salida similar a esta:

```
nueva: 5
aplazada: 2
nula: 10
etc
```

Como dije, he probado a hacer la query de arriba, pero me devuelve un error y a parte no se como agrupar para hacer esa salida...

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que he conseguido la consulta que querías.

Unos apuntes para futuras preguntas que quieras hacer.

UNO
No es necesario que pases la estructura completa de las tablas en tu base de datos, basta con que incluyas los campos más **relevantes**, es decir, aquellos que sirven para relacionar las tablas entre si y aquellos que quieras que salgan en el resultado final de la consulta.

DOS
Tampoco te va a pedir nadie que pases los datos reales de tu base de datos, pero sí puedes proporcionarnos un juego de datos mínimo con datos ficticios. Indicando el resultado que has obtenido hasta ahora y el resultado que quieres obtener.

Dicho todo esto, he simplificado tus tablas para quedarme con las columnas relevantes y he generado un pequeño juego de datos para probar que obtenía los datos que quieres. Son los siguientes:

```
CREATE TABLE LLAMADA (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  nomape varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  id_teleoperadora int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  id_estado int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
  
CREATE TABLE CITA (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  id_llamada int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  id_estado int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
  
CREATE TABLE CITA_ESTADO (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  descripcion varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
  
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  id_empleado varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
  
INSERT INTO CITA_ESTADO (id, descripcion) VALUES
(1, 'NUEVA'),
(2, 'CONFIRMADA'),
(3, 'PENDIENTE'),
(4, 'NULA'),
(5, 'APLAZADA'),
(6, 'AUSENTE'),
(7, 'VENTA');


INSERT INTO CITA (id, id_llamada, id_estado) VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 2, 2),
(3, 8, 54),
(4, 4, 6),
(5, 77, 1),
(6, 6, 5),
(7, 88, 1),
(8, 8, 7),
(9, 9, 7),
(10, 10, 7),
(11, 21, 4);


INSERT INTO LLAMADA (id, nomape, id_teleoperadora, id_estado) VALUES
(1, 'Ricardo Rubio', 1, 5),
(2, 'Ricardo Rubio', 1, 5),
(3, 'Ricardo Rubio', 1, 3),
(4, 'Ricardo Rubio', 1, 5),
(5, 'Ricardo Rubio', 1, 8),

(6, 'Ricardo Rubio', 2, 5),
(7, 'Ricardo Rubio', 2, 9),
(8, 'Ricardo Rubio', 2, 5),
(9, 'Ricardo Rubio', 2, 5),
(10, 'Ricardo Rubio', 2, 5);


INSERT INTO USERS (id, id_empleado, nombre) VALUES
(1, 'TEST01', 'Trujillo, Juan'),
(2, 'TEST02', 'Luque, Ignacio');
```

La consulta que obtiene las citas asignadas por un teleoperador concreto agrupadas por su descripción sería

```
SELECT U.ID, U.NOMBRE, CONCAT(CE.DESCRIPCION, "(", CE.ID, ")") AS ESTADO, COUNT(C.ID)
FROM USERS U
JOIN LLAMADA L ON U.ID = L.ID_TELEOPERADORA 
JOIN CITA C ON L.ID = C.ID_LLAMADA 
JOIN CITA_ESTADO CE ON C.ID_ESTADO = CE.ID 
WHERE U.ID_EMPLEADO = 'TEST01'
AND L.ID_ESTADO = 5
GROUP BY U.ID, U.NOMBRE, CE.DESCRIPCION
ORDER BY U.NOMBRE, CE.DESCRIPCION;
```

Para mi pequeño juego de datos, con solo dos empleados y un cliente, obtendría

```
ID  NOMBRE          ESTADO          COUNT(C.ID)
1   Trujillo, Juan  AUSENTE(6)      1
1   Trujillo, Juan  CONFIRMADA(2)   2
```

Nótese que no he empleado la tabla LLAMADA_ESTADO porque no necesito la descripción del estado de la llamada en principio. Tampoco necesitaría componer con la tabla USERS si ya sé el id del teleoperador pero la he incluido por si quisieras buscar por su id_empleado en lugar de su id.

Si ya disponemos del id del usuario y no necesitamos recuperar más datos de la tabla USER, podemos simplificar la consulta como

```
SELECT L.ID_TELEOPERADORA, CE.DESCRIPCION, COUNT(C.ID)
    FROM LLAMADA L 
    JOIN CITA C ON L.ID = C.ID_LLAMADA 
    JOIN CITA_ESTADO CE ON C.ID_ESTADO = CE.ID 
    WHERE L.ID_TELEOPERADORA  = 1
    AND L.ID_ESTADO = 5
    GROUP BY L.ID_TELEOPERADORA, CE.DESCRIPCION
    ORDER BY CE.DESCRIPCION;
```

Obteniendo

```
ID_TELEOPERADORA    DESCRIPCION    COUNT(C.ID)
1                   AUSENTE        1
1                   CONFIRMADA     2
```

Que es muy parecido a tu resultado requerido.

Prueba la consulta y si tus datos reales presentan alguna peculiaridad que no he contemplado, edita tu pregunta - intentando aplicar mis dos apuntes, para simplificarla - y añade esa información.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta!! me has salvado la vida xD.